# How can you build a REST client, given that the client should have no prior knowledge excepting a starting url?

Tags: java, flash, rest, web-applications, client

I've started work on a pre existing REST application and am having trouble understanding how one would go about making a RESTful  client?

The page on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Guiding_principles_of_the_interface) states the following

"Clients make state transitions only through actions that are dynamically identified within hypermedia by the server (e.g. by hyperlinks  within hypertext). Except for simple fixed entry points to the application, a client does not assume that any particular actions will be available for any particular resources beyond those described in representations previously received from the server."

If all the client can assume is a starting url then apart from a pure HTTP rest service running in a browser how would it be possible for the client to know how to display any information returned.

For example a java/flash client would have to make an assumption about what data is returned in order to know how to display it, ad then of course the implementation would cease to be restful??

Thanks for any insight.

Piers

Comment: I see what way you read it, but I would take it simply as meaning that you should ensure your app is robust in it's locating of the resources and in how it tolerates errors (such as lacking resources etc.), and not actually that you shouldn't make assumptions on the data. For example, if you're making a microbloggin app, you can expect the data to be in the format defined by the platform, but try to ensure your app is smart about resolving URIs to the resources you're looking for and tolerating discrepancies/errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a difference between state transitions and telling the client how to display the information. In HTTP the data type is usually determined by the `Content-Type` header field based on which the client decides on how to display it (e.g. a browser would request `text/html` and render the result). REST does not make the assumption that the data are self describing, just that they should be semantically connected through URIs. What the wiki page states is that if you are requesting `application/json` at `http://example.com` it will return something like this:

```
{
    "users" : "http://example.com/users",
    "todos" : "http://example.com/todos"
}
```

Now you know what URI to request to get a list of todos and a request to `http://example.com/todos` might return something like this:

```
[
    {
        "description" : "Do dishes",
        "user" : "http://example.com/users/20"
    },
    {
        "description" : "Do dishes",
        "user" : "http://example.com/users/42"
    }
]
```

Instead of just returning an id, the user key references the actual URI for the connected user resource, so you can directly request it.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that in reality, for most popular REST APIs that I've dealt with anyway, the trend tends to be to provide a list of objects (as the todos in this example) with basically the complete objects and not just a URI, paginated if necessary. It would be impractical to require 100+ separate requests to display a list of 100 todos... the single item URI would tend to be mostly used solely for _update_ and _delete_ calls.

Comment: Cheers Daff & garmur, I feel like I'm at least one step closer to getting my head around this thing!

Comment: Alternatively you could also create a user object with the data you need for displaying it but still keeping the reference (to stay with the actual REST spirit): `"user" : { "href" : "http://example.com/users/42", "username" : "John Doe" }`